# Storing hexadecimal bytes in Big Endian from Little Endian

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I have this snippet of code here, which reads a file, using a program counter that begins at 0

It iterates by 4 bytes since each instruction is 4 bytes long (32 bits)

Now my current code

```
 for (i = 0; i < filesize; i += INSTRUCTION_SIZE) {
        fread(&blob.instruction_memory[i], 1, INSTRUCTION_SIZE, file);
    }
    for (program_counter = 0; program_counter < INSTR_MEM_SIZE; program_counter += INSTRUCTION_SIZE) {
        unsigned char instruction[INSTRUCTION_SIZE];
        for (int j = INSTRUCTION_SIZE - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            instruction[j] = blob.instruction_memory[program_counter + j];
        }
        init_instruction(instruction);
    }
    fclose(file);
```

Reads the file, iterates it by 4 bytes (each instruction), then stores each instruction into the instruction array

A visualization

PCounter at 0 = Instruction 1

PCounter at 4 = Instruction 2

PCounter at N/4 = Instruction N

Now suppose I read in an instruction in the format of 0x13,0x01,0xF0,0x7F

This represents the binary 00010011 00000001 11110000 01111111

However I do not want to store these instructions in my instruction[] like this rather I want it in Big Endian

So like this

7F F0 01 13

and the binary representaiton for reference: 01111111 11110000 00000001 00010011

How do i go about doing this?

Comment: Try `htonl`.....

Comment: SUGGESTION: look at the source code for [htonl()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl): https://github.com/klee/klee/blob/master/runtime/klee-libc/htonl.c

Comment: Did you try to swap the bytes yourself. That's pretty straight forward, 2-3 lines of simple code at max.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way will be during the read from file (first loop in your code).

```
for (i = 0; i < filesize; i += INSTRUCTION_SIZE) 
{
    for(int byte = 3; byte >= 0; byte-- )
        fread(&blob.instruction_memory[i + byte], 1, 1, file);
}
```

Do not worry about reading one byte. I/O operations are buffered and the performance penalty will not be noticeable.

Comment: While the absolute penalty is not that big, the relative penalty compared to reading in the correct order then swapping is probably huge, especially when you consider that the x86 has a byte swap instruction.

Comment: @ikegami I do not think that it will be the most important in the OPs code :)  Judging from the question - simplicity is king

Comment: Swapping bytes is no more complex than reading bytes backwards -- it's simply `mem[byte] = buf[4-byte]` instead of `read(&mem[i + byte], 1, 1, file)` -- and it's even simpler on a system with `htonl`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the instructions are saved in little-endian in the input file, you can reverse the order of bytes to store in big-endian.

```c
unsigned char instruction[INSTRUCTION_SIZE];
for (int j = 0; j < INSTRUCTION_SIZE; j++) {
    instruction[j] = blob.instruction_memory[program_counter + (INSTRUCTION_SIZE - 1 - j)];
}
```